# Pytz - Time is off when transforming from one timezone to another (by 11 minutes)

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I am trying to transform time (say, 15 hrs) from eastern time to 
Uruguay's timezone (eastern time + 1 hr). Then I try to convert display 
from 15 to 15:00.

The problem is when doing this transformation I keep getting 11 extra 
minutes and I can't solve why. Please help?

My code right now:

```
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
uruguay = pytz.timezone('America/Montevideo')

print("Top 5 Hours for comments in Uruguay's time:")
for avg, hr in ordered_avg[0:5]:
    time_1 = dt.datetime.strptime(str(hr), "%H")
    time_2 = eastern.localize(time_1)
    time_3 = time_2.astimezone(uruguay).strftime("%H:%M")
    print('{}: {:.2f} average comments per post'.format(time_3, avg))
```

Results for the first row of the loop when printing them:

```
time_1 = 1900-01-01 15:00:00
time_2 = 1900-01-01 15:00:00-04:56
time_3 = 16:11
16:11: 28.68 average comments per post
```

Expected results (which are not okay right now):

```
time_3 = 16:00
16:00: 28.68 average comments per post
```

Comment: What happnes when you print `time_2.strftime("%H:%M")`?

Comment: The result is '15:00' (eastern time, not Uruguay's)

Comment: If you don't care fot he minutes, why not do `strftime("%H:00")` ?

Comment: That would work, I was just hoping to get what is wrong.